# Disable service worker for a sub-directory

Tags: service-worker

I have a web app with a service worker that is registered at a root level of a domain. It provides basics offline capabilities.

I do not want the service worker to engage when request is made for a particular sub-directory e.g. /example/

I can add this check within the service worker, but is it possible to completely disable the service worker for a specific path?

Or set up another worker from the sub-directory, so that it will override the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the SW scope is global by default. But judging by this reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register

There should be possible to use the scope option to restrict the scope of your service worker to narrow it. But not in the sense that you can restrict a subfolder. You will need to move that subfolder out of the service worker scope.

IE: you move the folder in question in the main directory, then move all the other folders in the ./website location.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Register a service worker hosted at the root of the
  // site using a more restrictive scope.
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: './website'}).then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
  }, /*catch*/ function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
  });
} else {
  console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

If this doesn't help the only option that comes to my mind is the one you mentioned.

Comment: I found this article useful that describes how to define scope of the service worker to certain folders at install time - https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2999382&seqNum=5